# Getting html textarea with Node JS express returns undefined

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I'm trying to get input from the following textareas and turn it into a bunch of keywords

```
<form method="POST" action ="/input" enctype="text/plain">
        <p>Enter the keywords you would like first with spaces in between</p>
        <textarea name ="keys1" id="editBox" rows="5" cols="5"></textarea>
        <p>Enter the keywords you would like second with spaces in between</p>
        <textarea name ="keys2" id="editBox" rows="5" cols="5"></textarea>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

However whenever I run the following code (see below) I get the error TypeError: Cannot read property 'keys1' of undefined. How do I fix it? I looked at some other questions but their solutions don't really work (or I don't understand them).

Code that returns the error:

```
app.post('/input', function(req, res) {
    var firstkey = req.body.keys1;
    var secondkey= req.body.keys2;
    var keylist1 = firstkey.split("+");
    var keylist2 = secondkey.split("+");
    if(keylist1.length>0 && keylist2.lenght>0){
        var output = [];
        for(i=0; i<keylist1.length; i++){
            for(j=0; j<keylist2.length;j++){
                output.push(keylist1[i]+" " + keylist2[j]);
            }
        }  
        res.send('<a href="/">Upload more</a><br>' + output.join('<br>'));
    }
});
```

Comment: mounted `body-parser` ?

Comment: the error means `req.body` is undefined - so, nothing at all to do with textareas etc